# SentTestCase doesn't highlight UnitTest failures as errors in code

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, xcode, ios4, ios

I have setup UnitTests for some of the logic of my iphone app, I followed apple's guide for UnitTests in XCode, however when some of the assertions fail - instead of highlighting the place directly in code like a regular compilation error - XCode just displays the number of errors in the bottom-right corner and I have to look up the errors in the output log. Does anyone know what additional steps one has to take to make XCode highlight assertion failures in UnitTests like regular errors in code?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in Xcode. I don't think it has worked for at least  as long as version 3.2.x but it might have broken earlier. I filed a bug report with Apple back in march but it got closed as a duplicate so they are aware of the problem. I don't imagine it will get fixed in the 3.X incarnation since Xcode 4 is on its way.